# Voltage between neutral and ground in receptacle

Tags: electrical

I have 10 outlets on the circuit. The first two check out fine. The rest show 120V between hot an d neutral and hot and ground. But they show 57V between neutral and ground. I unhooked the hot to a receptacle and still got 57V between neutral and ground? Any answers?

Comment: Phantom voltage

Comment: What precipitated this? Receptacles that stopped functioning?

Comment: This seems VERY similar to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/192655/120v-on-hot-and-neutral-wires-just-started-happening), and my answer there applies to you here.

Answer (score 1):

The 56V is just a nonsense figure you are getting because you have a high impedance voltmeter, and it doesn't know what to do with what it's seeing.  This is the sign of a wire that is entirely disconnected from anything.

It's not attached at the panel side (because of a defect), and it's not attached to hot via any loads, because you have removed them.

If you plug in a load and turn it on, then the neutral should start behaving more predictably.  This will also correct for the error produced by your meter.

Comment: "This will also correct for the error produced by your meter" - Isn't that error only produced by the operator, and not by the meter?

Comment: @xeeka The only operator error is not being aware of the existence of phantom voltage and that it is the likeliest explanation for readings like this.  It's mostly the meter just giving a voltage reading where no real electro-motive force exists.

Comment: "the meter just giving a voltage reading where no real electro-motive force exists" - is it not simply a voltage source with a high impedance? This high impedance being the small capacitance between galvanically isolated wires?

Comment: @xeeka I suppose you could think of it that way.  As an educator I would be reluctant to go down that path, since it will only serve to confuse.  "Such readings are junk readings" is really the point that will help them the most.

Answer (score 0):

For a TN-C-S net, **Neutral and Ground have to be connected**, ideally at a location close to the hole where the incoming cable of the power provider enters the building. If the 3rd ff. outlets do not have a very low voltage next to zero G-N , most likely either the **ground or the neutral wire or even both are interrupted** somewhere between 2nd and 3rd outlet.

Thus the disconnected Ground and/or Neutral wire is on a "floating" status, showing **misleading voltages** with a high impedance multi meter. A device like a hairdryer should be switched on during measurement.

Here is more information on phantom voltages:
[Voltage Neutral - Ground](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/192655/120v-on-hot-and-neutral-wires-just-started-happening)

Comment: A hair dryer would do the trick, but not the best choice because you can't (or shouldn't) leave it on for several minutes while troubleshooting, running around the house to different receptacles, etc. Better would be a light (but not a super-small LED load) or a radio.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact A hairdryer could be laid and blocked on a fire proof ground. It is an ohmig impedance even for the smallest voltages that will stay on after power  interruptions. LED lights may have a very high impedance at low voltages, radios may have electronic switches, i.e. would remain off after resetting power, which would be a very dangerous misleading effect.

Comment: Agree as far as LED. And as far as radio, depends on design, but in some cases you're right there too. Which gets back to Harper's usual of "Incandescent night light". Small, low power (much safer than hair dryer), simple circuit (unlike radio, etc.).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact A hairdryer reveals also a lose contact problem if the hot-neutral voltage differs too much between full power and switched off - thus avoiding domestic fires. And electric work should only be donewith a second person present.

Comment: ... and hair dryers aremuch more common then incandescent (night) lights. In areas with high kWh-prices, incandescent lights have become collectors' items.

Comment: *electric work should only be done with a second person present.* Yes, when it comes to certain things. But routine stuff can be done by one person as long as they know how to do so safely.